# In a multidimensianl array how should I set the keys as a value of my array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this `$courses` variable. The result of `var_dump($courses)` is this:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> array(8) { ["course_name"]=> string(11) "Mathematics" ["day_of_week"]=> string(1) "1" ["start"]=> string(8) "10:00:00" ["end"]=> string(8) "12:00:00"  ["course_id"]=> string(4) "1111" }
[1]=> array(8) { ["course_name"]=> string(7) "Physics" ["day_of_week"]=> string(1) "2" ["start"]=> string(8) "12:00:00" ["end"]=> string(8) "14:00:00" ["course_id"]=> string(4) "2222" } 
[2]=> array(8) { ["course_name"]=> string(7) "History" ["day_of_week"]=> string(1) "5" ["start"]=> string(8) "10:00:00" ["end"]=> string(8) "12:00:00" ["course_id"]=> string(4) "5555" } }
```

What would be best practice to make `course_id` the key of each internal array so the result would be:

```
array(3) { 
['1111']=> array(8) { ["course_name"]=> string(11) "Mathematics" ["day_of_week"]=> string(1) "1" ["start"]=> string(8) "10:00:00" ["end"]=> string(8) "12:00:00"  ["course_id"]=> string(4) "1111" }
['2222']=> array(8) { ["course_name"]=> string(7) "Physics" ["day_of_week"]=> string(1) "2" ["start"]=> string(8) "12:00:00" ["end"]=> string(8) "14:00:00" ["course_id"]=> string(4) "2222" } 
['5555']=> array(8) { ["course_name"]=> string(7) "History" ["day_of_week"]=> string(1) "5" ["start"]=> string(8) "10:00:00" ["end"]=> string(8) "12:00:00" ["course_id"]=> string(4) "5555" } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short solution using `array_column`(available since PHP 5.5) and `array_combine` functions:

```
$courses = array_combine(array_column($courses, "course_id"), $courses);
// now $courses contains the needed result
```

Answer (score 1):

#### PHP >= 5.5

You can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to [reindex an array](https://eval.in/584775):

```
$reindexed = array_column($courses, null, 'course_id');
```

From the manual, the second parameter can be null for this exact purpose:

> It may also be `NULL` to return complete arrays or objects (this is useful together with `index_key` *[third argument]* to reindex the array).

#### PHP < 5.5

You can use a simple [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to [recreate the array](https://eval.in/584777):

```
$reindexed = array();
foreach ($courses as $values) {
    $reindexed[$values['course_id']] = $values;
}
```